# jupyter-notebook is not working after jupyter-notebook command

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda, jupyter-lab

I'm setting up a jupyter-notebook to work with data science related projects. I am not able to install it properly or there is some issue with compatible versions. I started with Anaconda Navigator it is not launching from and does not give any error.

I followed the steps as mentioned in the https://jupyter.org/install still It is not launching. I have updated conda, jupyter and I also have the latest python.

Following is my setup -

```
(base) C:\Users\Sameer>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\Sameer\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Sameer\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Sameer\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.5
    conda-build version : 3.18.7
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=9.1
       base environment : C:\Users\Sameer\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Sameer\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Sameer\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Sameer\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Sameer\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Sameer\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Sameer\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.6.8 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


(base) C:\Users\Sameer>jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.5.0
jupyter-notebook : 5.7.8
qtconsole        : 4.5.1
ipython          : 7.6.1
ipykernel        : 5.1.1
jupyter client   : 5.2.4
jupyter lab      : 0.35.4
nbconvert        : 5.5.0
ipywidgets       : 7.4.2
nbformat         : 4.4.0
traitlets        : 4.3.2

(base) C:\Users\Sameer>python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()

(base) C:\Users\Sameer>jupyter-notebook
```

I am expecting "jupyter-notebook" command to launch the browser. Kindly let me know where can I get the logs to go ahead and fix it.

Comment: I have windows 64 bit operating system but my python is saying on 'win32' is that an issue ?, have I installed wrong python ?..

Answer (score 0):

What is your output when you type "jupyter notebook"?

What you might also consider is working with jupyter lab. That allows imho a nicer way of working.

Comment: I am not getting any output after typing the command "jupyter notebook" and also "jupyter-notebook", jupyterlab is not launching in Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Fix - I uninstalled Python and reinstalled it again. It started working,  wait here is a trick - when you run the jupyter-notebook windows python permission should be enabled,  I had accidentally missed this when I ran it for the first time. It showed me second time and I enabled it...  It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `pip install jupyter` on cmd or terminal with python 3.8. Then after installing type `jupyter notebook`

Note that I didn't use a hyphen. I have also not used conda, just pip